# reloading a table in html using php to get values from database

Tags: php, html, database

I have an html page which displays a table. The values in the table are taken from database.
The columns of the table are : name, score, birthDate.

I added two calanders on the top of the table using :

```
<input type="text" id="id1" name="start_date" class="form-control input-lg ff-1 required datepicker pointer" value="">
```

I added another one for the end_date.

what I need is :

When the user selects start and end dates, I want the values in the table to be refreshed, and only entries with date between start_date and end_date should be displayed.
I know how to include both date values in the sql query and so on, but how can i trigger this query and how can i replace the values which are already present in the table with the new values .

Note: I do not need sample code, I just need to know the steps please as I am new to php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some javascript here:

1. Attach event on changing dates in calendar or on clicking some button.
2. In event's handler make an ajax request to server and pass dates to server script.
3. Server will return plain html or some json, use some jquery (for example) methods to clear current table content and insert new one.